# convert an int to a char*

Tags: c++, c++11, string-formatting

i cant get the following to work:

```
char* int_toChar ( int num ) {
    char* str = "0";
    if ( num != 0 ) {
        char* prefix = "";
        char* chars = " 123456789";
        int id = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < num; ++i ) {
            str = prefix + chars[id];
            if ( id == 9 ) {
                id = 0;
                //prefix = (char*)("") + chars[id];
            } else {
                ++id;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

this function i made because i want to use printf_s rather then cout, but i want a function that converts a int to a char* so that i can use it in other functions apart from printf_s

Comment: Basically a `stringstream` is a good way to go. This has been asked many a time here.

Comment: I see no memory allocations in this function whatsoever, and it doesn't take a string as an argument. There's no way you're going to get a legitimate pointer out of this.

Comment: Firstly, `char*` is a *pointer to a `char`*, not a *`string`*. But besides this, you say you "want to use printf_s rather then cout". Why? Particularly when you've tagged yout question with C++11, this makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

I mean this in the nicest way possible, but there are so many things wrong with this function it's hard to say where to begin:
-you are looping over num, your input.  I'd hate to see what happens if you I gave your function the number 2000000000.
-char* is not an array of characters.  It is a pointer.  You cannot return it like it was a value, because the memory pointed to by str ceases to be yours after this function returns.
-in line 8 you are adding a pointer to a character

If you really wanted to get something like this working, it seems to me that you have a bit to learn about the C language, pointers, and how C handles strings.  I would just use sprintf(str, "%i", num); for now if you want to avoid cout.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems start here:

```
 char* str = "0";
```

A string literal is not writable memory.

It just gets worse after that.

Why not use `itoa`?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to allocate some memory in which to put the converted int somehow, either statically or dynamically.  If you allocate a static buffer, then you can write the converted int into it and return a pointer to it just as the interface to your posted function shows, but the char* string you'd be returning would only continue to contain that number until the next time you called the function.  Alternatively you could dynamically allocate a buffer in which to put the converted int's characters (either using malloc() or new), and then the caller of your function would be responsible for later free()'ing or deleting the allocated buffer, or else you'd have a memory leak.  If you know up front that your function would only be used a limited number of times to create fixed number strings, especially ones that need to exist for the life of your program, then you wouldn't necessarily have to free/delete them.  Be sure whatever way you allocate it, you allocate enough space for the largest numeric string you might need to create, probably  based on the size of an int (12 chars would be sufficient for representing any positive or negative 32-bit integer value).

Now once you have the memory buffer allocated, you'll need to write the decoded int value into it.  You can do that with your own custom-rolled looping which would certainly involve the use of / and % (divide and mod) operators which I don't see in your code, or preferably, use an already-available standard library function to do that for you.  One way would be to use sprintf(myBuffer, "%d", num).